# What does it mean if the (German) PhD I applied for keeps extending its deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, germany, deadlines

The PhD position I am applying for has extended its deadline (fully funded PhD at a German university). This post has already been extended 4 times, the first deadline was 30 July, then 31 August, then 31 October and now 30 November. I applied in October and I still have no reply (at least not knowing that I have been rejected).

What could be going on? Is it OK to ask about the status of my application?

The other positions offered in the same research project but in different departments already have someone.

Answer (score 3):

How to proceed is to keep looking for other positions, not depending on this one working out.

The usual reason for extending deadlines is an insufficient number of applications (or submissions to conferences) that are considered viable. That may mean you are not being considered seriously, but it may not. If the rules require "fair treatment" of all applications, then they probably can't admit anyone until they close applications.

Yes, you can ask for status, but it might not result in much useful information. You haven't been definitely rejected, however, so there is some hope yet.

Comment: Note that this is the same basic answer given in the Workplace discussion. You're doing a job hunt. Most of the same best practices apply. Including not assuming you have the job until you have a written commitment and start date.